# Spree online shop and Paypal Authorization & Capture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, spree

I'm currently trying to get the Spree shop system to work with Paypal. I'm using this gem: https://github.com/spree/spree_paypal_express

I want to use the Authorization & Capture method from paypal, to capture the customers funds after I checked if all the items are available. Unfortunatly, I haven't found this method inside the gem. Can anyone provide some information, how to setup this? I'm new to all the Paypal stuff (on the dev side ;), and I think sometimes the API really confusing.

So maybe someone has already done a Authorization & Capture with Spree and can give me some hints.

Answer (score 0):

I have used paypal a little.

https://gist.github.com/4165500

also if that did not help you can checkout http://railscasts.com/episodes/141-paypal-basics

That link above is what I built my paypal off of. Also you can checkout this other payment system that came threw Hacker News. https://gethelium.com/?ref=hn

Also here is some documentation on paypal basics

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide.pdf

It is a big pdf but it has some good information. As for the spree gem sorry to say I have not used it. can't be sure if it is any good. Hope these links help you.

Comment: Oh forgot this link. it is directly on paypal express http://railscasts.com/episodes/146-paypal-express-checkout

Comment: thx for the links, I already found that documentation and the railscast. I think I have to have a deeper look in it ;) But maybe some other guy has used the spree gem